# NUnit Test with an array of values

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to use NUnit with the values attribute so that I can specify many different inputs without having 100 separate tests.

However now I am realizing there are times where I want to use the same set of inputs but on very different test like below.

Is there a way that I can specify all the values in one place, like an array and use the array for each values attribute?

I want to make sure that the test runs as 100 individual tests, instead of 1 test that runs 100 values.

I have looked in the Nunit documentation, but I cannot find a way to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Code:

```
[Test]
public void Test1([Values("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", ... "Value100")] string value)
{
    //Run Test here
}

[Test]
public void Test2([Values("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", ... "Value100")] string value)
{
    //Run Test here
}

[Test]
public void Test3([Values("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", ... "Value100")] string value)
{
    //Run Test here
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`TestCaseSource` attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.2) is suitable here.

See example:

```
private string[] commonCases = { "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };

[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(commonCases))]
public void Test1(string value)
{
    ....
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(commonCases))]
public void Test12(string value)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FactoryAttribute` on test method, instead of `ValuesAttribute` on param. Read more about this [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=factory&r=2.5).

**Edit:**
Alexander is right. FactoryAttribute was a temporary part of API. The right path is to use [TestCaseSourceAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.2).

Answer (score 0):

`ValueSource` is also an option, especially if you want to combinatorically provide values for multiple test parameters. For example:

```cs
public class Tests {
  public static string[] firstValues = { "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };
  public static string[] secondValues = { "Val4", "Val5", "Val6" };

  [Test, Combinatorial]
  public void Test(
    [ValueSource(typeof(Test), "firstValues")] firstValue,
    [ValueSource(typeof(Test), "secondValues")] secondValue
  )
  {
     ....
  }
}
```

Comment: I learned this approach from this helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16347477/473792